# Auto-alignment in GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

My cards are indented 25dp
**first screen**

[image]

And after I start scrolling down, the bottom cards that are behind the screen, themselves redefine their location.

**strong text**
 [image: image2]

How does this happen? Ideally, I would like to use this on the first cards, so that they are also self-determined.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/Main_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logo_image_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/user_recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:splitMotionEvents="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, the question is a bit vague.

Comment: @H.Brooks I myself do not understand what is happening. Why are the bottom cards rearranged?

Comment: What do you mean with rearrange?

Comment: @H.Brooks auto-alignment, shift